# printing float/double using printf crashes the program

Tags: embedded, printf, powerpc, newlib

I am working on a **syscall** implementation for a **PowerPc**.
I have tested some gcc functions and they all seem to work (e.g. sqrt sin cos pow printf malloc...)

I recently realised a problem with the **printf**. it works fine as long as I print some integer/char but when I try to printf **%f/lf** to print float/double the program crashes. (it seems to be executing somewhere it should not be)

I have checked the makefile, it uses:

```
# use soft float
CFLAGS += -msoft-float
```

and when making the program I can see many **nof** (no float) libraries being linked.

```
gnu/powerpc-eabi/3pp.ronetix.powerpc-eabi/bin/../lib/gcc/powerpc-eabi/4.3.3/../../../../powerpc-eabi/lib/nof\libm.a)lib_a-s_sin.o
```

I also know that I have enough space in stack/heap so that should not be a problem.
*It there still a reason why **printf** should crash when printing float?*

Comment: syscall implementation? Kernel space or user space??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your newlib is probably built without support for floating-point IO.  This is fairly common for embedded systems as it saves a lot of code space.  You can probably rebuild newlib to support floating-point IO.  I *think* the configure options are `--enable-newlib-io-float` and `--enable-newlib-io-long-double`.  You can probably find out for sure by running `./configure --help`.

Comment: I haven't used newlib but I've used other embedded C libraries and had similar issues.  printf() still exists and can handle integer and string IO.  It's just that printf() can't parse the %f specifier and it can't handle a floating-point parameter.